# Filling dropdowns in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, select

I have a table in an angularjs view built with ng-repeat.
In each table row there is a button.
If you click on the button a details row is shown.

This details row has a form and another ng-repeat-table.

In the second table there are buttons for delete and edit.
The form contains two dropdown inputs to edit the content of the second table's row.

If I click on either the delete or edit buttons in the second table should fill the form fields (the dropdowns) with the passed data.
How would I do this programmatically using angularjs?

Comment: Please share some, what have you tried so far?

Comment: The script is on a computer without internet access so copying is not possible.
<form><select ng-model="object"><option ng-repeat="option in options" ng-selected ="object.value==option"></select></form>
The select list is filled, so the option in options works properly.
But the ng-selected is not correct. 
I tried also $parent.object.value==option but no success either.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are trying to do this:

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <select ng-model="select1" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in Items">

   </select>
   <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in Items">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="Edit(item)">Edit</a></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.Items = [
    {
        id: 1,
      name: "ABC"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
      name: "DEF"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
      name: "GHI"
    }
  ]
  $scope.Items.unshift({id: 0, name: '--select--'})
  $scope.select1 = 0;

  $scope.Edit = function(item) {
    $scope.select1 = item.id;
  }
}
```

Comment: The select is part of a form with all fields of item (e.g. item.type to stay in your example).
Those form fields are shown as dropdowns (selects) and I want to fill the data of the selected item (which is passed by Edit(item) into the form showing the data of item.